# <br > element automatically added by input formatting

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

when I add a tag  in a input text area in drupal back-end, a 
 element is automatically added after the tag .

Could you explain me how can I disable this ?

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably have the convert linebreak to `<br />` option enabled for the filter.

http://grab.by/grabs/b84afdaf805eea9c07033efbda57ba04.png

Answer (score 3):

On the settings for the input format, where you see the list of filters enabled, disable the "Line break converted" filter.

[Screenshot http://img.skitch.com/20100806-jg4xwb6pyp1ymgg6hqwmuyb75c.png](http://img.skitch.com/20100806-jg4xwb6pyp1ymgg6hqwmuyb75c.png)